# Confusion on how to solve this question about sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Write down the first five values of each of the following recursive sequences:
$$
s_0 = 2, \quad   s_n = s_{n−1}^2 + s_{n−2}^2 + \cdots + s_0^2
$$
for all integers $n \geq 1$.

Approach: Say for $s_1= s_0^2 + s_1^2 + s_0^2$ which means $s_0^2 + s_0^2$ since $s_1$ isn't greater or equal to $1$.

So is the answer $8$ or just $s_0^2$ which will be $4$? I am confused by this part $[\ldots + s_0^2]$.

Comment: Please use proper math formatting. I can't even edit your post because I don't understand it. You mean :
$$
s_0 = 2,\ \ s_n = s_{n-1}^2 + s_{n-2}^2 + ... + s_0^2
$$ ? Then what do you mean by "$s(1)$" ?

Comment: I have a feeling it's supposed to be $s_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}s_j^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $s_0=2$ and $$s_n=s_{n-1}^2+s_{n-2}^2+\cdots+s_0^2$$

This way of writing it just means we sum the squares of every term from $s_{n-1}$ down to $s_0$. If $s_{n-1}=s_0$ then $s_0^2$ is the only term in the sequence.

This means that the next term is equal to the sum of the squares of all the previous terms, that is to say $$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}s_k^2$$

Therefore, we can say that:

\begin{align}s_1&=s_0^2\\
s_2&=s_1^2+s_0^2\\
s_3&=s_2^2+s_1^2+s_0^2\\
s_4&=s_3^2+s_2^2+s_1^2+s_0^2\end{align}

So, we have \begin{align}s_1&=2^2=4\\
s_2&=4^2+2^2=16+4=20\\
s_3&=20^2+4^2+2^2=400+16+4=420\\
s_4&=420^2+20^2+4^2+2^2=176400+400+16+4=176820\end{align}

So, the first five terms of the sequence are $$2,4,20,420,176820$$

Comment: Just for the fun : $s_{10}\approx 6.95 \times 10^{335}$